# Plaid transactions unavailable 2 minutes after a user connects their bank account (PRODUCT_NOT_READY)

Tags: plaid

I'm currently accessing user's plaid bank transactions using this approach:

1. User connects to plaid through the plaid web/iframe component
2. 2 minutes later `POST /accounts/balance/get` is called, which returns a list of bank account ids (`account_ids`)
3. The transactions for the bank accounts retrieved in 2. are requested using `POST transactions/get`

`transaction/get` then gives the following error: `PRODUCT_NOT_READY : the requested product is not yet ready. please provide a webhook or try the request again later`

---

**What I'm unclear on is how to trigger plaid to start pulling transactions**. The [documentation](https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/webhooks/#pulling-transactions) mentions that 30 days of transactions are available after ~10 seconds of "connecting an item to link". Is the user connecting to plaid through the iframe considered connecting to link (since it calls `POST /link/item/create`)? Ideally I can get access to the transactions **without having to use webhooks**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure to initialize Link with the `transactions` product in your call to `/link/token/create`? That would be the most likely source of the error -- the Item won't start fetching transactions on link unless `transactions` is specified in the `products` parameter of the `/link/token/create` call.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize opting-in was necessary - that was the issue.

This part of the documentation made it clear: https://plaid.com/docs/link/best-practices/#choosing-when-to-initialize-products. Not sure if it'd be helpful to mention that in https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/webhooks/#pulling-transactions